# Why are there methods that are capitalized in a list of private methods?

Tags: ruby

When I run `1.private_methods`, I get the next output:

```
1.private_methods
=> [
:initialize_copy, 
:default_src_encoding, 
....
:format, 
:Integer, 
:Float, 
:String, 
:Array, 
:warn, 
...
:Rational, 
:Complex, 
:gem, 
...
]
```

I see some methods here whose names match a class name like `Integer`, `Float`, `Array`, or `String`. How is it possible? What are they actually? Are these methods?

Comment: Ok, but how these methods appear here? As I know some of these classes are placed in other 'branch' in basic classes structure. Especially the String. (see the [image](http://screencast.com/t/32B0zhGeW))

Comment: Because all this methods are implemented in `Kernel` module, which is mixed into `Object`.
Check this for reference:
http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Kernel.html

Comment: Thank you. Could you provide me some links where I can read about how and where they used (just really interesting:))?

Comment: I think I already did. `Kernel` module documentation shows examples of use of some of these methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, these are regular methods. Ruby allows capitalized method names. If it didn't, things like

```
Array(1..3)
# => [1, 2, 3]
```

wouldn't be available.

Comment: But I thought that all starts with capitalized char is a Constant, no?

Comment: @DmitriyKonovalov as you see, no. Method names can start with capitalized letters.

Answer (score 2):

Just like a method starting with a lower case is ambiguous with a local variable, a method starting with an upper case is ambiguous with a constant (class, module being special cases). The reason you don't hit these methods when you simply write `Integer`, `Float`, etc. is because there is a rule that says to interpret them as a local variable or a constant rather than as a method when it is ambiguous. When you want to use them as a method, there is always a way to resolve the ambiguity, such as (i) attaching parentheses for arguments, (ii) writing a receiver and a period before them.